# Odoo Website AccessError No value found for product.template(6,).qty_available

Tags: xml, authentication, web, odoo, qweb

I edited the template.xml for website_sale in order to place the quantity available on the product screen. I successfully did this by adding following line of code:

```
<p>Available: <span t-esc="'%.0f'%(product.qty_available)"/></p>
```

Now I can see the qty available BUT ONLY AS ADMINISTRATOR(or user created from settings > users), whenever I log in with another user created from sign up button, I get following error:

> QWebException: ('AccessError', 'No value found for product.template(6,).qty_available')

Any ideas what this might come from? Maybe because the 'qty_available' field is just a function field? Or because there are not security rules set for this field?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AccessError` always happen due to access  rules .

So either create/modify the access rules(provide read access `1,0,0,0` to all type of user inside `security/ir.model.access.csv`) for such field/model or just use `sudo` with the field like:

```
product.sudo().qty_available
```

**NOTE:** Creating the security rules is always the decision as it provide the access control feature which can very particular user to user.

Regarding:`function/compute field`:

`function/compute  field` creating the issue only at the time of `search` as non store-able(`store=Flase`)  is it default property , which can be modify by setting `store=True` which is not true in your case.